# Why does textmate modify the file mtime after closing the tab?

Tags: vue.js, electron, textmate, textmate2, electron-vue

I use electron-vue to automatically reload the page, and every time I close the file, textmate automatically update mtime of the file. This was not the case before, and I don't know why.

Comment: Have you tried older versions of TextMate? If you could narrow it down to a release, it could probably get fixed. If I were you, I'd ask this question again on the mailing list https://lists.macromates.com/listinfo/textmate

Comment: @Graham P Heath Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via the mailing list;

> The reason is that TextMate uses extended attributes to store things
>   such as position of insertion point, selection etc.
>
> You can disable this via `.tm_properties`. Create a `.tm_properties` file
>   in the root of your project and let it contain this line:
>
> `disableExtendedAttributes = true` You can also create the file in `~` to
>   disable the behavior globally, or you can limit it to certain file
>   types, e.g. by using:
>
> `[ *.vue ] disableExtendedAttributes = true`

-- Allan Odgaard